# ImageIcon does not show up for a checkbox

Tags: java, swing, awt, imageicon, jcheckbox

I want to add an icon instead of default square box of a check box. Whenever i add icon the only checkbox label views, no icon or default square box shows up. Why icon is not viewed.. I have searched a lot.. but nothing works for me
Here is the code..

```
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class againcheckbox extends  JFrame implements ItemListener
{
    //frame and panel
    ImageIcon image1=new ImageIcon("logo4.png");
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JCheckBox c1=new JCheckBox("College");
    JCheckBox c2=new JCheckBox("University");
    JCheckBox c3=new JCheckBox("Both");
    JLabel l1=new JLabel();
    public againcheckbox()
    {
        panel.add(c1);
        panel.add(c2);
        panel.add(c3);
        panel.add(l1);
        c1.setIcon(image1);
        c2.setIcon(image1);
        c3.setIcon(image1);
        c1.addItemListener(this);
        c2.addItemListener(this);
        c3.addItemListener(this);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),"select"));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        JCheckBox test=(JCheckBox) e.getItem();
        String str=test.getText();
        l1.setText(str);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        againcheckbox acb=new againcheckbox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the icon located relative to the source

Comment: It is located in the list of src files of the project..

Comment: As an icon i am using a blue colored square box. this icon is at same location as other icons which are used in other programs and work very well.

Comment: does not work for these well -->>>checkbox.setRolloverIcon(image3);       
        checkbox.setSelectedIcon(image2);       
        checkbox.setDisabledIcon(image1);

Comment: It works just fine in this simple example `BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Look at me!", new ImageIcon(image));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, checkBox);` ..

Comment: The conclusion I draw from that is that `ImageIcon image1=new ImageIcon("logo4.png");` is **not** where you think it is.  Further, application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: It is helpful.. thanks

Comment: *"It is helpful.."*  Without knowing who you are replying to, it is hard to know what it is that you found helpful.  Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment, and identify what it was that helped.

Comment: It was helpful to know about embedded resources.. @AndrewThompson thanks

Comment: Good one!  I see you have got the hang of notifications.  Note that the person that asked a question *always* gets notified of new comments, which is why I can afford to 'ignore' the advice I offered to you (and leave out the `@name` notification).  ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace

```
ImageIcon image1=new ImageIcon("logo4.png");
```

with

```
Icon image1=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("logo4.png"));
```

Comment: Don't post guesses. You can't answer the question because the OP did not show their file structure.